# Subtracting two dates in php

Tags: php

I have got two dates in php

```
$date1 = 'May 3, 2012 10:38:22 GMT'

$date2 = '06 Apr 2012 07:22:21 GMT'
```

Then I subtract both of them

```
$date2 - $date1
```

, and get

```
Result:6
```

Why is the result 6 and not 27? ... ? How can I subtract the two dates, and make it return me a result based on month differences while subtracting the  years & days & time ?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Part 1: Why is the result 6?

The dates are simply strings when you first subtract them.  PHP attempts to convert them to integers.  It does this by converting until the first non-number.  So, date2 become 6 and date1 becomes 0.

Part 2: How do you get it to work?

```
$datetime1 = strtotime('May 3, 2012 10:38:22 GMT');
$datetime2 = strtotime('06 Apr 2012 07:22:21 GMT');

$secs = $datetime2 - $datetime1;// == <seconds between the two times>
$days = $secs / 86400;
```

Convert as appropriate.

Comment: Do I need to convert the seconds between two times..to days... isnt there a faster way

Comment: seconds in a day = 60*60*24 = 86,400 so just divide by that.

Comment: This solution won't work for different factors like months, years, etc. It works for days, but I wouldn't use it to measure anything else. Instead, use the DateTime class with "diff" method to extract the actual days, months, years passed. See other answers for implementations that you should use (instead of seconds passed)

Comment: As mentioned @GM `diff` doesn't work if it's more than a month. Dealing with time properly is exceedingly difficult - did you account for daylight savings, regional time zones, leap years, leap seconds, etc? That said, if you have a better solution that this one that is over 10 years old, please post it! I'm sure there have been some updates since then.

Answer (score 26):

Using [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) and [DateInterval](http://php.net/DateInterval),

```
$date1 = new DateTime("May 3, 2012 10:38:22 GMT");
$date2 = new DateTime("06 Apr 2012 07:22:21 GMT");
echo $date1->diff($date2)->format("%d");
```

Comment: This will return me the difference in days..cause thats what I want..to find the date difference

Comment: if the difference is more than a month, `format("%d")` would't account for that. So it's not perfect! Use `echo $date1->diff($date2)->days;` instead.

Comment: This is not the right answer, mostly cause DateInterval is a terrible object: `$date1 = new DateTime("May 3, 2012"); $date2 = new DateTime("06 Apr 2013"); $date1->diff($date2)->format("%d") // == 2`


Also,  `->days` is sometimes false: `(new DateInterval("P2Y100D"))->days // === false!`

Comment: `$diff->invert` is available for comparison (0 is positive, 1 is negative)
also you can use `date_timestamp_get` to get timestamps from the DateTime objects and work with absolute seconds

Answer (score 14):

There is one way to use mktime n make the date in timestamp and then subtract and then use date function to show in the way u want....

Other way is that format both of dates in the same format then subtract....

Third way

```
$date1=  new DateTime("May 3, 2012 10:38:22 GMT");
$date2= new DateTime("06 Apr 2012 07:22:21 GMT");
echo $date1->diff($date2)->("%d");
```

forth way

```
$datetime1 = strtotime('May 3, 2012 10:38:22 GMT');
$datetime2 = strtotime('06 Apr 2012 07:22:21 GMT');
$secs = $datetime2 - $datetime1;// == return sec in difference
$days = $secs / 86400;
```

Answer (score 8):

Most of presented solutions seems to be working, but everyone forgets about one thing: time.

Taking **evan** example:

```
$datetime1 = strtotime('May 3, 2012 10:38:22 GMT');
$datetime2 = strtotime('06 Apr 2012 07:22:21 GMT');

$secs = $datetime2 - $datetime1;// == <seconds between the two times>
$days = $secs / 86400;
```

When you don't trim time part, what might lead to milscalculations. For example: Interval between `2014-05-01 14:00:00` (Y-m-d) and `2014-05-02 07:00:00` will be 0,xxx, not 1. You should trim time part of every date.

So it should be:

```
$datetime1 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('May 3, 2012 10:38:22 GMT')));
$datetime2 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('06 Apr 2012 07:22:21 GMT')));

$secs = $datetime2 - $datetime1;// == <seconds between the two times>
$days = $secs / 86400;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$todate= strtotime('May 3, 2012 10:38:22 GMT');
$fromdate= strtotime('06 Apr 2012 07:22:21 GMT');
$calculate_seconds = $todate- $fromdate; // Number of seconds between the two dates
$days = floor($calculate_seconds / (24 * 60 * 60 )); // convert to days
echo($days);
```

This code will find the date difference between two dates..

Here output is 27

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 'time'.$notification_time=  "2008-12-13 10:42:00";
 date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
 echo 'cureen'.$currenttime=date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
$now = new DateTime("$notification_time");
$ref = new DateTime("$currenttime");
$diff = $now->diff($ref);
printf('%d days, %d hours, %d minutes', $diff->d, $diff->h, $diff->i);
```

Comment: `$diff->invert` is available for comparison (0 is positive, 1 is negative)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use diff(it returns a Dateinterval object) method, the correct way is to format with %a. I mean:

If you check http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

The correct way is:

```
 echo $date1->diff($date2)->format("%a");
```

For getting all days

Comment: a method name was omitted, correct is: 
echo $date1->diff($date2)->format("%a");

Comment: `$diff->invert` is available for comparison (0 is positive, 1 is negative)