# PHP time subtraction from 2 variables

Tags: php, datetime, duration, subtraction

I am trying to subtracting two variables in PHP (time format, "H:i:s"), i.ex:

```
$entryscan = '07:15:00';
$exitscan = '16:35:00';
```

How do I get the work duration? 
I mean `$workduration = $exitscan - $entryscan;`
so, the answer is `$workduration = '09:20:00';`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtract time in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463549/subtract-time-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtracting two dates in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469037/subtracting-two-dates-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get total time difference between two dates using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696654/get-total-time-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use php **[timediff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)** function.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime($entryscan);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($exitscan);
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%H hours');
```

**%H** will give you the difference in **hours**.

**%I** will give you the difference in **minutes**.

**%S** will give you the difference in **seconds**.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use php DateTime Class if your php version >= 5.2

```
$entryscan = '07:15:00';
$exitscan = '16:35:00';

$entryTime = new DateTime($entryscan);
$exitTime = new DateTime($exitscan);
$interval = $entryTime->diff($exitTime);
$workduration = $interval->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$entryscan = '07:15:00';
$exitscan = '16:35:00';
$time1 = new DateTime($entryscan);
$time2 = new DateTime($exitscan);
$diffis = $time1->diff($time2);
echo $workduration = $diffis->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

@Arshid i just edit your code is working fine.