# subtract date in 2016 from current date in php

Tags: php

I want to subtract one date in 2016 from current date  using php and display day.How i do this using php . can anyone help me . please give suggestion

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtracting two dates in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469037/subtracting-two-dates-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

check this code snippet

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->modify('-1 day');
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Based on the number of day you need to put the parameter  $date->modify('-{**NoofdaystoSubstract**} day');